# Is Contract Processor Module available for free trial in google document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am already free trialling the google invoice processor of the document AI. But now I have another use case to process contracts. Is Google Document AI for contracts available for free trial. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#specialized_processors) Contract parser is under a specialised processor. Also it is on [preview](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) stage...

- **Preview** offerings are often publicly announced, but are not necessarily feature-complete, and no SLAs or technical support commitments are provided for these

...and access status is set to limited, it means that you will have to request access by filing a "Contract AI limited access customer request [form](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#footnote3)", The form requests information about you, your company, and your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. I had submitted the form. Is there a timeline on when i will be hearing back from the Team

Comment: Just an FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [cloud-document-ai]